# Multiple negative analog signals to positive signals

Tags: arduino, analog, negative

I have multiple analog DC signal of sensors each connected via a coax cable. The outer layer of the coax cables needs to be grounded into a metallic wall for EMC capabilities radiation safety, thus I only have the inner conducting part coming through the wall on the other side.

The problem is that for each analog DC signal, the inner conducting part have less potential than the outer (negative polarity -0.1 to -1.1), and I want to read this using an Arduino only allowing positive voltages between 0-5 V. So what would be a good way to turn the negative analog DC signals positive?

Inverting the signal with inverted op-amps does not work if I understand correctly. I tried simulating (using Farstad's tool) voltage divider using the same 5 V supply for each signal and it acted weirdly (output voltages changing rapidly), but worked well when simulated using one signal. How to wire voltage divider for multiple signals and only one power supply? I also read about op-amp adders, maybe better than dividers?

I will have to buy stuff so I wanted to ask first. What is the best way forward?

Comment: Please provide a schematic of your inverting opamp. It should work. Do you have one per channel feeding into separate ADC pins of your MCU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the "best" solution depends of your requirements.

The simplest solution is to simply use a voltage divider towards a positive voltage rail (for example the 5V or 3.3V rail of your arduino).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fASfFe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can compute Vout by supperposition (putting once Vin to 0V, then Vcc to 0V, and summing the 2 resulting voltages) :

Vout= R2/(R1+R2) * Vcc + R1/(R1+R2)*Vin

The first part will give you a positive offset, the second part is the attenuation of your signal (like a classical voltage divider).

In practice, choose your resistors such as in your worst case you get Vout just above zero (this way, you avoid attenuating too much your signal).

This is I think the simplest solution, but at the cost of some attenuation of your signal (ie some loss of resolution). If your worst case is -1.1V, you should be able to keep the precision loss quite low.

NB : make sure Vcc rail is present before the input, otherwise you get a negative voltage on Vout (it might still be OK if your resistors are high enough by making use of the ESD diodes, but I strongly advice to check very carefully the datasheet before you take the risk).

If this solution don't meet your requirements, then I think you will need to use some amplifier(s). For normal op amps, the input has to be above the negative supply rail (sometimes it can be equal, sometimes you need a few volts margin). So if you don't have a negative voltage rail, you will need to add one.

Once you have a negative voltage rail, a simple inverting amplifier can be enough (you might add some gain if you want).

If you want to map your input voltage range to the full range of the arduino (0-5V), you can do it with a single op-amp and a few resistors. You can have a look at [this application note from  TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf) that covers all the calculations to add arbitrary gain and offset, or to map an arbitrary range to another arbitrary range.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a negative rail to make an inverting amplifier, as long as the output will always be positive (i.e. the input will always be negative). You just need an op amp that can accept inputs very close to its negative rail. The MAX4230 might work.

Comment: @Sandro thank you, perfect just what I needed! The precision could potentially be a problem as you said so I will look into the offset versions a bit more from the link.

Comment: And as @Hearth pointed out, you might get away with an op-amp that can work with inputs just bellow its negative supply (not common, but I think there are some), in which case you can avoid generating a negative rail